# Overly-broad questions that would be useful to Drupal developers, and have a good answer

Tags: discussion, questions

Re: [What tools do I need to automate my Drupal workflow?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33232/what-tools-do-i-need-to-automate-my-drupal-workflow)

This question is obviously not a good fit for the site, as defined by the FAQ, as it's very broad in nature.

However, I'm sure nearly any Drupal developer would love to have a definitive answer to this question. Also, the [given answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33232#answer-33243) is actually a very good one. Anyone who doesn't know about the QuickStart project would surely be delighted to find out about it (I know I was when I first came across it).

That said, and if anyone agrees with me, how should questions like this be handled? I can think of three scenarios (please feel free to add more):

1. The question should simply be closed (and hopefully not deleted).
2. The question should be edited in some way to make it on-topic for the site.
3. The question should be left as is and not closed.

Personally I'm torn between them all.

What does everyone else think about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems too broad to me, but the fact there is a tool that does exactly what asked by the user could make the question acceptable. (I take Drupal Quickstart can be used for all the tasks required from the OP, not just a part of them.)

It would be acceptable if the answer is more detailed, and it provides more information (even through more links) about Drupal Quickstart. If this is possible, then the question can be made a Community Wiki.

To make a comparison, it would be like having a question that lists some features required from the OP, and that are features implemented in the Views module. If the answer would just say "There is the Views module," it would not be much helpful, and so would be the question.
Clearly, there is a difference between my hypothetical question, and the one you are asking for: The Views module is probably more used, and popular. Pointing out the existence of Drupal Quickstart in a question could be helpful, but the answer should be more detailed, IMO.

Comment: I think that's where I'm struggling...the answer addresses about 90% of the points in the question, not every last detail unfortunately. Would that make it an unsalvageable question in your opinion? Good luck with the election on SO by the way :)

Comment: If the answer gives more information, I would re-open the question; at least, the project is not one of those well known projects.